# Tree data structure in Julia

Tags: data-structures, julia

I need to implement a simple (but not binary) tree in Julia. Basically, each node needs to have an integer ID, and I need a convenient way to get a list of children for a node + add child to an existing node by ID.

e.g. 0->1->(2->(3,4,5),6)

where each number represents a node, I need the functions children(2) and add(7 as child of 4).

I am aware that similar tree implementations can be found for other languages, but I am pretty new to OOP/classes/data structures and not managing to "translate" them to Julia.

Comment: A Tree can be seen as a special case of a directed graph. Directed Graphs, in turn, are implemented in `Graphs.jl` and `LightGraphs.jl`. But maybe some dedicated data structure is better.

Comment: Is there any reason this would be slower than a dedicated data structure? Beyond the first compilation of `Graphs.jl`, that is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You didn't state whether you want the IDs to be assigned automatically as new nodes are added, or if you want to specify them when you add the children (which would involve some form of more complicated lookup).
If the IDs can be assigned, you could implement a tree structure as follows:

```
type TreeNode
    parent::Int
    children::Vector{Int}
end
type Tree
    nodes::Vector{TreeNode}
end
Tree() = Tree([TreeNode(0, Vector{Int}())])
function addchild(tree::Tree, id::Int)
    1 <= id <= length(tree.nodes) || throw(BoundsError(tree, id))
    push!(tree.nodes, TreeNode(id, Vector{}()))
    child = length(tree.nodes)
    push!(tree.nodes[id].children, child)
    child
end
children(tree, id) = tree.nodes[id].children
parent(tree,id) = tree.nodes[id].parent
```

Otherwise, you might want to use `Dict{Int,TreeNode}` to store the tree nodes.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. I realized afterwards that I'll never need to add new children to the tree, only reassign them to other nodes, but this seems achievable by a small change to your `addchild()`.

Comment: Would it be better for `nodes` to be a `Dict`? It would be easier/less expensive to add/remove/modify the tree structure.

Comment: `Dict`s can be very expensive compared to a simple vector. You might mark deleted `TreeNode`s in the above structure by setting the parent to a -1, for example, and check that on reading, so that removal of a node would be easy.  It really depends on the use case though.  As I said in my answer though, if the IDs are assigned, then you would want to use a `Dict{Int, TreeNode}`.